# StringTemplate does not respect NumberFormat

Tags: string-manipulation, number-representation

I am trying to write Latex report generator for my standard data analysis. But there is an issue with formatting numbers I can not get around. I would like to make use of my own `NumberFormat` and `StringTemplates`s but the last reformats the numbers. Here is an example:

```
n = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert@Quantity["PlanckConstant"]
```

> 6.626070*10^-34

```
ScientificForm[n, 3, 
 ExponentFunction -> (If[-10 < # < 10, Null, #] &), 
 NumberFormat -> (If[#3 != "", Row[{#1, "e", #3}], #1] &)]
```

> 6.63e-34

```
StringTemplate["A: ``"]@%
```

> A: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000066260696

Is there a way to make `StringTemplate` output the numbers in a format I have specified? I guess the problem might have something to do with underlying `TextString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default [`InsertionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InsertionFunction.html) for [`StringTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html) is [`TextString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextString.html); use [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) instead:

```
SetOptions[StringTemplate, InsertionFunction -> ToString]
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug, here is simple workaround:

```
StringTemplate["A: ``"]@ToString@%
```

> ```
> "A: 6.63e-34"
> ```